# How Cassandra identifies the node for replication in a multi data center multi rack multi node setup

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I understood that Cassandra tries to replicate data across different rack - different DC to handle fail over...
For Example :  Suppose I have a total 8 node cluster spanning across 2 different DCs, each DC having 2 racks.

Node 1 - DC1 RACK 1  |  Node 2 - DC1 RACK 1 | Node 3 - DC1 RACK 2 | Node 4 - 
 DC1 RACK 2 | Node 5 - DC2 RACK 1 | Node 6 - DC2 RACK 1 | Node 7 - DC2 RACK 2 |
 Node 8 - DC2 RACK 2

Now if I have a RF of 3, then while writing a row ,
    Cassandra will store 1st copy of the row on the node(let say in this case Node 1) which is responsible for the token range of row 1. 
    So 1st replica is stored in let say : Node 1 which is under DC 1,RACK 1 
Now Cassandra  needs to store 2 more replicas to fulfill RF =3 critria.

1) Let say to handle Rack failure & to have local read  it store 2nd replica in some node in the same DC but different RACK.
   So 2nd replica will be stored in either Node 3/Node 4 which are in DC 1,RACK 2. 
   My Question is what basis will Cassandra choose Node 3 or Node 4.  How it figures out why Node 3 gets prefreed over node 4 or vice versa.

2)To handle DC failure, it store 3rd copy in other DC (which is DC2).
    Now it is 2 options:
        a) It has to choose one of the racks between Rack 1 and Rack 2 in DC2.
            - my 2nd question is on what basis/logic does it choose among multiple Racks in the same data center.
        b) Lets imagine, if it chooses Rack 1 in DC 2, then it has to choose between Node 5 or Node 6 for the replication.
            - my 3rd question is on what basis Cassandra chooses the node with in Same Rack ? (It is basically same as 1st question)

Comment: Possibly better to ask on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the replication strategy you choose for your keyspace.
In `SimpleStrategy` it just takes consecutive nodes on the ring - this is meant as a simple strategy for a single DC (I'm guessing you don't use this but added for completeness)

in `NetworkTopologyStrategy` you need to define the number of replications per DC and Cassandra will walk the ring clockwise until reaching the first node in another rack.
see: [Cassandra data replication docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeReplication.html?hl=replication)
and [a blog with nice visuals](http://distributeddatastore.blogspot.co.il/2015/08/cassandra-replication.html)

Regards,
Jony

Comment: One more question .. If each DC has 2 racks and each rack is having 2 Nodes. Lets say replica of 1st row is stored in ( Node 1(RAC 1, DC 1), Node 3(Rac 2,DC 1), Node 5(RAC 1,DC 2) .. This is keeping in mind the the clock wise walk along the ring.(Check the cluster structure I mentioned in the question). Now for 2nd row insert, Lets say Node 2 in RACK 1 DC 1 is responsible for the token range,

Comment: Hi, Take into consideration that each DC will hold the entire token range - and inside a DC, Cassandra will try to split the data among racks.

In your case above you have 2 DCs with 2 Racks - if you want a RF 3 in each DC you will hold 6! copies of the data - 3 in each DC.
e.g, nodes 2,3 & 1 in DC1 and nodes 6,7 & 5 in DC2.

Comment: Got Your point, So while creating key space we mention how many replicas in the same DC ... If I mention "WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 3 } " , then no data will be stored in DC2, only DC1 will have 3 copies ( two in rack 1, one in rack 2). In this scenario will DC 2 ever get data to store?

Comment: Hi, with `NetworkTopologyStrategy` you specify the RF per DC - so you could put all data in one DC or replicate among 2 DCs.

if you want to split your data across DCs - you need to write them as a single DC - note this is a very bad idea as you will easily get split brains...

yes - the way you just wrote will keep all. data in DC1.

Comment: In an environment like FB where volume is huge and data in a KeySpace needs to be geographically distributed...how can we design the storage?Lets say table Users contains info about all the users and I want to segregate user info in multi data center,  Lets say all user from India should be stored in a DC-INDIA , all user from US should be stored in a DC-US. How can it be achieved ?

Comment: A billion users spread over 50 servers in a dc is just 20 million in a server - usually fits into memory ...  Cassandra is built for scale - don't fear it 